# Umbrella header 'DKImagePickerController-umbrella.h' not found

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

When I build a project in debug, no problem.

When I try to archive it, I got:

/Users/Francois/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/1001_b_v0.5-dwrktwhwtbzbhcddlogdytbebeni/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/DKImagePickerController.build/unextended-module.modulemap:2:19: Umbrella header 'DKImagePickerController-umbrella.h' not found

What i've tried:
 - Delete Derived data
 - Tried to put DKImagePickerController "public"

DKImagePickerController was imported via pod.